# Is there any performance difference when using not equal vs just equal

Tags: c++, performance

I'd expect the compiler would magic this away for you, but, could there be any performance difference between the following two blocks of code?

```
        if (! something.isTrue) {
            pathFalseFunc();
        } else {
            pathTrueFunc();
        }
```

and

```
        if (something.isTrue) {
            pathTrueFunc();
        } else {
            pathFalseFunc();
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope! If you see [assembly level code](http://assembly.ynh.io/) of both the blocks they will look same. So, no difference at all.

Here the assumption is that you aren't overloading `!` operator. If you overload `!` operator then second block will be more efficient, just by tiny bit (off-course, it will depend on how you are overloading the operator).

Comment: Really like the assembly website

Comment: I use it quite often ;)

Comment: The contextual conversion to `bool` may not be faster than `operator!`.

Comment: That proves there is no difference for one particular compiler using one particular set of options, but in theory, *a* compiler could render one version more efficiently than the other. In practice this is unlikely, but the only way to be sure is to check the output from the particular compiler you're using.

Comment: @dlf: We've seen cases where **previous** input made a difference. The biggest issue might very well be the CPU's branch predictor.

Comment: @Ike it is actually ;)

Answer (score 6):

Normally, there will be no performance difference as Abhishek has pointed out. However, it will be a totally different story if `something.isTrue` is a class type that has overloaded `operator!`. In this case, `!something.isTrue` calls `operator!` while `something.isTrue` calls for a contextual conversion to `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

As usual in HLL it depends upon the optimizer. But if we think at machine code level then there could be difference between taken jumps and not taken ones. Although it's architecture/alignment/hints dependent but usually it's better when runflow is more flat i.e. branching is taken on less probable condition.